# jquery: how to apply functions in HTML?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery.  I have a dynamically generated row with unique ID's.  I need to apply a jQuery function to each row.

My jQuery function starts immediately after the page is loaded instead of waiting for me to click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function popup() {
  $(this).hover(function() {
    $('div#pop-up').show();
  }, function() {
    $('div#pop-up').hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

I want the jQuery popup() function to do its thing when I click on the 'tr' row, and only affect that particular row.

```
<tr id="abc" onclick="popup()">
  <td>blah</td>
</tr>
<tr id="def" onclick="popup()">
  <td>blah</td>
</tr>
<tr id="ghi" onclick="popup()">
  <td>blah</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a selector to specify which element(s) the function should apply to, and then pass that selection into the appropriate jQuery method:

```
$('tr').click(
    function(){
        popup();
    });
```

In the above the function `popup()` will be called only once someone clicks on a `tr` element (or its children, since the click will bubble).

You could also use `on()`, if any of the `tr` elements are to be added dynamically following the initial DOMReady event:

```
$('tbody').on('click','tr',function(){
    popup();
});
```

With `on()` the events are bound to the element closest to the dynamically-added elements, and the method is passed an event-type (`click`) and, optionally, a selector (`tr`), to determine which elements will trigger the function(s) found within the method.

Though remember, depending on what element(s) you're using for the pop-up, that an `id` can be used for only one ***unique*** element within the document.

Reference:

- [The jQuery API selectors index](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

call Onclick like with `this`

```
<tr id="abc" onclick="popup(this)">
  <td>blah</td>
</tr>
```

Then change `popup` to

```
function popup(elem) {
  $(elem).hover(function() {
    $('div#pop-up').show();
  }, function() {
    $('div#pop-up').hide();
  });
}
```

Your syntax of

```
$(function popup() {
```

Is not correct it should be

```
$(function(){
     function popup() {
     ....
     ....
```

Comment: This method is kinda bad and really outdated. Event binding should happen in JavaScript.

Comment: @DvirAzulay, Yeah I know, I just checked his way of doing this and corrected the code. I should suggest using event binding.

Answer (score 0):

Add class to '*popup*'able elements:

```
<tr id="abc" class="pop-up-class" >
  <td>blah</td>
</tr>
<tr id="def" class="pop-up-class" >
  <td>blah</td>
</tr>
<tr id="ghi" class="pop-up-class" >
  <td>blah</td>
</tr>
```

Then in your script:

```
$(function() {
  $('.pop-up-class').hover(function() {
    $('div#pop-up').show();
  }, function() {
    $('div#pop-up').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work.  Now my jQuery function does not work at all

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant to bind the `click` event to the TR rows instead of just calling that function.
The right way to bind functions to DOM elements is by binding callback functions to them.
This allows you to define a callback function to a set of elements, and then execute code in the context of the element that triggered the event.
When an event is triggered the binded callback is executed, and `this` becomes the DOM element.

Also, your jQuery code should be wrapped in an event that will be triggered when the DOM is ready; At that point it is certain that your DOM is done loading, making sure that the elements you want to bind your events to exist.

Finally,
you could re-write your callback like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr").on("click", function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {
        $("div#pop-up").show();
      }, function() {
        $("div#pop-up").hide();
      });
    });
});
</script>
```

For more explanations and example: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

You should also know:

- Inside the `hover` event `this` will be the context element as well, if you need to take action depending on the element being hovered.
- the jQuery `.on()` will bind events to elements matching the selector, even if they are not yet in the DOM, allowing you to insert elements dynamically and still have the events binded to them.